# Are there good locally decodable _erasure_ codes

Tags: coding-theory

> Are there known locally decodable *erasure* codes with
>   
>   linear codeword length and $\:n^{o(1)}\:$ query complexity?

According to pages 1 and 4 of [this link](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/yekhanin/papers/ldc_now.pdf) (which annoying does not give its own date,

though it cites references from 2011), locally decodable (error-correcting) codes

with linear codeword length are only known with query complexity $n^{\epsilon}$ for $\: \epsilon > 0 \;$.

i.e., Does considering *erasure* codes instead change that?

Such a code could be used for showing that a data host has *random access* to a given file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Locally decodable codes and locally decodable erasure codes are qualitatively equivalent. Both imply $\Omega(m)$ many disjoint $q$-tuples from which one can recover a given message coordinate, where $m$ is the codeword length and $q$ is the query complexity. A formal argument appears in Section 3.4 of [Kerenidis and de Wolf's paper](http://homepages.cwi.nl/~rdewolf/publ/qc/qldc.pdf).